# CPU Downclocks When Mouse Is Moved

Tags: windows, cpu, speedstep

My CPU is Intel i7 6700, I have speed step and all c states enabled. The spec says it can down clock to 0.7 when idle, but for me on a fresh Windows 10 install it ranges between 1.5-1.9.

However, if I move the mouse or drag a window it down clocks to between 0.8-0.9.

Task Manager says the CPU is on 0% usage.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: I'd guess its your application updating its output only when the system is non-idle. what tools are you using to view the frequency, and if you use multiple tools (speccy + cupz + whatever else), do they always agree?

Comment: @FrankThomas Task Manager says 1.6GHz at idle but cpu-z says all cores at 800MHz / x 8.00.

Comment: I'd trust CPU-z over Task manager any day. Try a few more tools and see which they side with. I also suspect that Task manager is not giving you per-core figures, nor is it accounting for the difference between hyperthreads and physical cores.